# How to use passport.authenticate if flag on user is set to true?

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js

I want to let the users log in to my webapp only if a flag/property called `isVerified` on the user is set to true(by default is false).

currently I have a login route:

`router.post('/login', authController.login);`

which goes the the `POST` login controller:

```
exports.login = passport.authenticate('local', {
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: 'Failed Login!',
  successRedirect: '/',
  successFlash: 'You are now logged in!'
});
```

But I want to only let the users be logged in, only if the `isVerified` flag on the user is set to true.

which would be set after they click on a link i sent them after registering.

This is what I tried so far, I changed the login method to do this:

When they try to login, i check if that user has the flag `isVerified` set to true
If is false, throw an error and redirect them to login, and tell them they need to click on the lin on the email.
If is set to true i want to log them in.

But it gets stuck.. just loading, what Im I doing wrong? this how I modified the login methid from above:

```
exports.login = async (req, res) => {

  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (!user) {
    req.flash('error', 'No account with that email exists.');
    return res.redirect('/login');
  }

  if (user.isVerified) {
    passport.authenticate('local', {
      failureRedirect: '/login',
      failureFlash: 'Failed Login!',
      successRedirect: '/',
      successFlash: 'You are now logged in!'
    });
  } else {
    req.flash('Warning', `Please verify your account by clicking on the link we sent you to ${req.body.email}`);
    return res.redirect('/login');
  }

};
```

Also I have passport setup like this:

```
passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Should you not do this logic in the strategy verify callback? aka where you set up the `passport.use`

Comment: I dont know.. should I? im new to this backend stuff. ill look into that online, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I am using the `passport-local-mongoose` package, and in their documentation the have an example on how to do exaclty this:

https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose#allow-only-active-users-to-authenticate